# How to mirror ipad on mac catalina

Tags: macos, ipad, mirroring

I have a MacBook Pro with macOS Catalina version 10.15.3 and an iPad mini with iOS 13.3.1.
I'd like to mirror the iPad to MacBook Pro.
I can extend the iPad using Sidecar but not the other way around.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the macOS built-in QuickTime Player app to mirror the display of any iPad device. You'd need to connect the iPad to your Mac using a cable for this to work.

Start by connecting your iPad to your Mac, launch QuickTime Player.app, and in the QuickTime Player menu bar, go to File → New Movie Recording (or alternatively, use the keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>).

This would open a QuickTime player window and activate the MacBook's built-in FaceTime camera. Now in the QuickTime Player window, click on the arrow shown besides the red colored record button, and under Camera, select your iPad.

[image]

This would change the contents of the window to display the iPad's screen instead of feed from the FaceTime camera. (Make sure that the iPad is not in sleep mode).

[image]

You are all set. You need not actually press the record button (which would simply start recording the iPad's screen). This way you have the iPad screen contents mirrored on your Mac.

Answer (score 2):

There are also a bunch of 3rd party tools with more advance options that can be used to mirror iPad's screen on a Mac.

1. [AirServer](https://www.airserver.com/Mac)
2. [Reflector 3](https://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector)
3. [ApowerMirror](https://www.apowersoft.com/phone-mirror)

Comment: `Apple has a built-in feature like AirPlay to mirror iOS mobile a device to another Apple device. With this, you will be able to mirror the iPad to Mac.` Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/lv-lv/HT204289

Comment: This link doesn't explain how you can AirPlay an iPad's display to Mac (as you stated).